# C# ProgressBar unexpected steps

Tags: c#, .net, progress-bar

I have a ProgressBar and a Timer.

I want to display the progress of 1 hour: increasing 1/3600 every second.

When I run the app, **after 30 minutes, the progressbar is at about 100%** progress.
I expected it to be at **50% after 30 minutes.** Why is that?

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        this.timer1.Interval = 1000;
        this.timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.progressBar1.PerformStep();
    }
```

-

```
        // 
        // progressBar1
        // 
        this.progressBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 29);
        this.progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 1000;
        this.progressBar1.Maximum = 3600;
        this.progressBar1.Name = "progressBar1";
        this.progressBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 23);
        this.progressBar1.Step = 1;
        this.progressBar1.TabIndex = 2;
```

Comment: timers aren't very good for measuring time, they are very imprecise (see Microsoft docs on that), you should set a `DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now` when you start the timer and use `(int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalSeconds` for the progess bar

Comment: Is your Timer's event already set on the `Designer.cs` file? If so, it's calling `timer1_Tick()` twice every tick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You added the timer from the toolbox and already set a tick event handler. This way it is actually called twice.